# Change Logo and Powered by OpenERP on Openerp 7 login page

Tags: python, openerp-7

I am doing Customization on OpenERP 7.
I want to change the Login page of Openerp. I want to replace the "Powered by OpenERP" to "Powered by ABCXYZ" and when we click on it should redirect to https://www.ABCXYZ.com
And also I want to change the Logo on the Login page from my custom module.

I have return a separate Custom module in which I am making changes on Project Module and Hr Module which is working fine. Now From the same module I want to make changes for the Login page. Is that posibble ?

My **openerp**.py file is

```
    { 
        'name': "ABCXYZ Custom Module",
        'version': "1.0",
        'author': "ABCXYZ",
        'category': "Project Management",
        'depends': ['web'],
        'data': ['custome_module_view.xml'],
        'demo': [],
        'auto_install': True,
        'qweb': ['static/src/xml/custom.xml']

    }
```

My **init**.py is

```
import custome_module
```

My static/src/xml/custom.xml file is

```
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="Login" >
        <t t-jquery=".oe_login" t-operation="replace">
            <div class="oe_login_footer">
                <a href="#" class="oe_login_manage_db">Manage Databases</a> |
                <a href="http://www.ABCXYZ.com" target="_blank">Powered by <span>ABCXYZ</span></a>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

Now when I am creating the static folder structure and and writing the above code I am coming up with 
"NO handler found" exception.
Can you please tell me what is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You can change them in base.xml which is present in your "Web"(addons folder) of addons.
Exact path is ../openerp/addons/web/static/src/xml/base.xml

you might find in

change the  .. as

```
<div class="oe_login_footer">
                <a href="#" class="oe_login_manage_db">Manage Databases</a> |
                <a href="http://www.ABCXYZ.com" target="_blank">Powered by <span>ABCXYZ</span></a>
</div>
```

and for image please place it in ../openerp/addons/web/static/src/img/
you can rename your image to logo2.png and place it over there

or

in  `<div class="oe_about">. ..</div>` you can give the path of your Logo

Comment: I want to do it from the custom Module. I don't want to make changes in the main openerp base files as when we upgrade it all of it will get washed away.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea hacking into a core module. Check out this post here https://accounts.openerp.com/forum/Help-1/question/How-to-remove-Manage-Databases-2615

Answer (score 0):

The below code will work:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="Login">
        <t t-jquery="div[class=oe_login_footer]" t-operation="replace">
            <div class="oe_login_footer">
                <a href="#" class="oe_login_manage_db">Manage Databases</a> |
                <a href="http://www.ABCXYZ.com" target="_blank">Powered by <span>ABCXYZ</span></a>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

Comment: I tied doing the above but I get the "No Handler Found " Exception. What are the other files I need to change. As of now I added  'qweb': ['static/src/xml/custom.xml'] to __openerp__.py file apart from that do I have to make any other changes. Even If I am adding a empty static folder in my module I am getting "No Handler Found" Exception.
Or is there any seperate module available which allows us to do changes to the login page. Even that will do for me ?

Comment: Check you log file for more details in the error. In the __openerp__.py file  you defined custome_module_view.xml file. Is it available in your module?..